# how to change default file that opens with Open Office?

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I looked up this question on google and found how to change the save file defaults, but not what files are opened when I double click the Open Office icon on my desktop.

When I double-click Open Office on my desktop I want it to open the Text Document every time, as that is all I ever need from it.
[image: Picture of what I'm looking to have opened every time the program is executed from the desktop.]

If this is possible, and you know a fix or a direct link to the way of doing this, I would be much appreciative. :) thanks, and have a great week!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shortcut for Writer.  If you are using Windows, press your Start button, then "All programs" or "All apps", then click on the OpenOffice folder and it will show you Base, Calc, etc. with Writer at the bottom.

Drag the Writer icon to your desktop to create a shortcut.  Double clicking on the Writer shortcut will open a text document.